# Websphere Application Server exception ADMC0016E: The system cannot create a SOAP connector to connect to host port

Tags: soap, websphere, port

After enabling administrative security on `Websphere Application Server 7.0.15 ND`, we are not able to stop the server `server1`. It says, that server appears to be stopped and not able to start the server `server1`:

> exception ADMC0016E: The system cannot create a SOAP connector to connect to host port 8881.

Deployment Manager is installed on the same server and able to access admin console.

Answer (score 1):

try to sycnhoronize Deployment Manager and node vis syncNode.sh utility from %node_profile/bin directory

```
./syncNode.sh dmgr_host -port port -user user -password password
```

then start node

Comment: Dear Andrey Please do note that this server profile is standalone profile, I am getting this error "Node is not incorporated into any cell" when fire syncNode.sh command.

Comment: U got 2 profiles on same server? Try to check if port 8881 available and not conflict with Deployment Manager port. Check SystemOut log of server1 that there were no messages like 'Port is already in use'

Comment: I created a new server with new profile. It worked for me.